# Java Create Theme From Image

Tags: java, android, image, themes

I'm a beginner developer (to GUI programming at least). Recently, I stumbled upon this: https://color.adobe.com/create/image/, which is an awesome tool that picks colors for a UI theme from an image. I was wondering if there is a way to implement something similar in Java?

If possible, these features would be nice:

- Different 'moods' of color picking modes (Similar to "Colorful", "Bright", "Muted", "Deep", and "Dark")
- Having it output a specified number of colors for each 'mood'
- Having each color output also have a corresponding body and text color (Similar to Android's Palette object).

So far I've tried:

- Making my own, which didn't really work - it always outputted almost identical colors for each category.
- Porting Android's to desktop, which would've worked but it was a major headache because I don't understand bit shift operators which it used heavily

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I did some more research and found a JavaScript one:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/

I googled around after finding that one and found a Java port:
https://github.com/SvenWoltmann/color-thief-java/

Which was almost perfect for what I needed, except I noticed it could be improved upon, so I created this by implementing Android's Swatch system into Sven's ColorThief:
https://github.com/iso2013/ColorExtractor

It has all of the features I requested implemented except for the different moods, which I didn't think was very important anyway.